# C# WPF How to convert native messaging --parent-window to IntPtr hwnd

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to convert the [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/nativeMessaging/#native-messaging-host-protocol) argument **--parent-window=<decimal handle value>** to a C# IntPtr hwnd value. The following code does not work:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint ProcessId);
foreach (string arg in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
{
    if (arg.IndexOf("--parent-window") != -1)
    {
        string[] subs = arg.Split('=');
        IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(subs[1], 16));
        uint pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, out pid);
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById((int)pid);
        Console.WriteLine(p.MainModule.FileName.ToString());            
    }
}
```

Can you help me to rewrite this so that it will display the filename of the --parent-window?

Comment: what is not working? you are not explaining the problem.

Comment: @TMcKeown Apparently IntPtr hwnd is not getting a window handle. So pid is 0. Therefore, I’m not able to reference the window and get a filename.

Comment: Remove `, 16`. The documentation says the value is decimal.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! That worked. But at first I got the error: "Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process." I had to go to the properties of the project > Build. Even though Platform Target was set to "Any CPU" I had to uncheck the box for "Prefer 32-bit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing comments, just try to convert to Int32 normally:

```
  IntPtr hwnd = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(subs[1]));
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. But at first I got the error: "Win32Exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process." I had to go to the properties of the project > Build. Even though Platform Target was set to "Any CPU" I had to uncheck the box for "Prefer 32-bit".

Comment: sounds like you'd be building this as x64